# group mysql query by field with same value and count

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have an SQL table that looks like so, but there are hundreds of thousands of rows:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+
| id   | timestamp           | lat       | lon        | country_code | city     |
+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+
| 2231 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 28.179199 | 113.113602 | CN           | Changsha |
| 2232 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 28.179199 | 113.113602 | CN           | Changsha |
| 2233 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 41.792198 | 123.432800 | CN           | Shenyang |
| 2234 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 31.045601 | 121.399696 | CN           | Shanghai |
| 2235 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 45.750000 | 126.650002 | CN           | Harbin   |
| 2236 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 39.928902 | 116.388298 | CN           | Beijing  |
| 2237 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 26.061399 | 119.306099 | CN           | Fuzhou   |
| 2238 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 26.583300 | 106.716698 | CN           | Guiyang  |
| 2239 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 39.928902 | 116.388298 | CN           | Beijing  |
| 2240 | 2013-09-22 14:58:32 | 31.045601 | 121.399696 | CN           | Shanghai |
+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

I need to query based on timestamp (intervals) and get all the records that fit within that interval, count the rows that have the same city (and add the lat/lon of any item, they will be all the same for the same group). Currently I just have a normal `select` and group in my application code (as per below) but this is slow since it needs to send over a few hundred kb to the application.

(python code to aggregate)

```
sorted_events = sorted(result, key=itemgetter('city'), reverse=False)
    for k, g in groupby(sorted_events, key=itemgetter('city')):
        group = list(g)
        first_item = group[0]
        unique_city_item = { 
            "city" : first_item['city'], 
            "country_code" : first_item['cc'], 
            "lon" : first_item['lon'], 
            "lat" : first_item['lat'], 
            "number_of_items" : len(group)
        }
```

It works the way I want it but it's slow. Is there a way to do this with an sql query directly? I get the following JSON output, I'd like something similar:

```
{
    {
        city: "Baotou",
        lon: 109.822197,
        country_code: "CN",
        lat: 40.652199,
        number_of_items: 288
    },
    {
        city: "Beijing,",
        lon: 116.388298,
        country_code: "CN",
        lat: 39.928902,
        number_of_items: 47
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select city, lon, country_code, lat, count(*) as number_of_items
from table t
where timestamp between STARTTIMESTAMP and ENDTIMESTAMP
group by city, lon, country_code, lat;
```